# cypress how to close the new window and back to main test window

Tags: cypress

I have written codes to click on hyperlink then check the new window URL.

```
   cy.get('a[href*="newlink"]').eq(0).click()
   cy.url().should('equal', 'https://www.google.com')
```

how do i close this window / or not close AND back to the original main test window?

Answer (score 3):

here's a solution i use for swapping between popup windows: https://github.com/jakedowns/CypressHelpers

it would need some tweaking to work directly with .click
but it does enable cy.openWindow and a new cy.switchWindow / cy.closeWindow

under the hood it uses an undocumented
`cy.state('document')` and `cy.state('window')` method for context-switching

Comment: hey any idea on how on button click or on window.open I can do this?

Comment: @Ankita I haven't used cypress in years sadly, i think they're STILL working on getting a update out that allows easier cross window / cross domain actions. When I last left off, I was using a custom page full of iframes to test interactions between pages. Maybe just assert that the href is correct, and skip asserting that the click opens the right window. There may be other workarounds nowadays too.

See: https://github.com/jakedowns/CypressHelpers/blob/master/frame_helpers.js 

And: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/944#issuecomment-1064967926

Answer (score 1):

```
cy.go(direction, options)
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/go.html#Syntax) for examples

This works for the history in the same tab. Cypress does [not support multiple tabs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Multiple-tabs).

Comment: The back button is not enabled at new window. By using direction back, still the new window staying open.

Comment: I think I raised a question and got answer. Cypress limitation not allowed to call the new window and only can perform test at one window. Hope my understanding is correct.

Comment: I didn't read close enough and will update my reply to account for that. If all this is answered elsewhere, feel free to delete.

Comment: i've added an answer which offers a workaround to window context switching

Comment: @jakedowns can you give solution on button click

Answer (score 0):

you can use cy.go('back')

see [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/go.html#Syntax)